# jqgrid dropdown list onclick of icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to show dropdown list in one cell of jqgrid an onClick of pencil icon(which when click the whole row become editable and dropdown list shows in debit credit )
below picture shows what i try to do

my approach is below code what i did
[image]

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''gridfucntion''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

function showMinorityEntryData(){
    alert('minoritydatashow');
    if($("#reportingPeriodId").val()!="" && $("#parentCmp").val()!=""){
        alert('minoritydatashow1111');
    //  $('#masterDiv').show();
         $("#grid").jqGrid({
          datatype: 'json',
          url:'showMinorityData.action?companyId='+companyId+"&parentCmp="+$("#parentCmp").val()+"&reportingPeriodId="+$("#reportingPeriodId").val(),
          mtype: 'GET',
             colNames:['Id', 'GlELEMENTNAME', 'Account Type','Pre-Acq-Amount','Share Amount','Actions'],
             colModel:[
              {name:'id',index:'id', width:55,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},hidden:false,jsonmap:"minorityId"},
              {name:'glElementName',index:'glElementName', width:100,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10},jsonmap:"glElementName"},
              {name:'accountType',index:'accountType', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, edittype:"select",formatter:'select',editoptions:{ value:  "Debit:Debit;Credit:Credit"},editoptions:{size:10},jsonmap:"acntTypeName"},
              {name:'preAcqAmount',index:'preAcqAmount', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10},jsonmap:"preAcqAmt"},
              {name:'shareAmount',index:'shareAmount', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10},jsonmap:"shareAmt"},
              {name:'actions',index:'actions', sortable:false,width : 50,align : 'center',formatter:actionIcons}
             ],
             
             postData: {
          },
             rowNum:20,
             rowList:[10,20,40],
             height: 200,
             autowidth: true,
         //    rownumbers: true,
             pager: '#pager',
             sortname: 'minorityId',
             viewrecords: true,
             sortorder: "asc",
             caption:"Minority Interest",
             emptyrecords: "Empty records",
             loadonce: false,
             loadComplete: function() {
          },
             jsonReader : {
                 root: "rows",
                 page: "page",
                 total: "total",
                 records: "records",
                 repeatitems: false,
                 cell: "cell",
                 id: "minorityId"
             },
             editurl: 'clientArray',
         });    
    }
}
```

i take help from this link `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610359/JqGrid-Inline-Editing`

but when i convert accountType cell in dropdown it doesn't show type of Account type below image shows what happen [image]

when i click on pencil icon the whole row become editable but in accountype column the dropdown doesn't show any value

[image]

what wrong i did it.
jqgrid is new for me

thanks in advance

Comment: What is `formatter:actionIcons`? Do you mean probably `formatter:"actions"`

Comment: you have to include `editoptions` or any other property **only once**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code you have to write this 
{name:'accountType',index:'accountType', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true},editoptions:{size:10},edittype:"select",formatter:'select',editoptions:{ value:  "Debit:Debit;Credit:Credit"},jsonmap:"acntTypeName"},
this will solve my requirement

Answer (score 1):

You should include `editoptions` or any other property **only once**. So

```
editoptions:{ value:  "Debit:Debit;Credit:Credit"},editoptions:{size:10}
```

need be replaced to

```
editoptions: { value: "Debit:Debit;Credit:Credit", size:10}
```

Comment: It's very simple in general. the syntax `{ value:  "Debit:Debit;Credit:Credit"}` means anonymous object with the property `value`. You can define `var myVal = { value:  "Debit:Debit;Credit:Credit"};` and use `editoptions: myVal`. In the same way the element of `colModel` is also anonymous object. If you define one object you can't specify **two different value for one property**. What you wrote before was the same like: `var colModelItem = { editoptions: oneValue, editoptions: anotherValue};`. It's syntax error. What I suggested is just fixing the syntax of your JavaScript code.